# Is it possible for an Adventurers League character to buy a magic item during downtime?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league, downtime

The Dungeon Master's Guide lists price ranges for magic items related to their rarity. For example, an uncommon magic item can be worth between 101 and 500 gold pieces. Consummable magic items are worth half the price of their permanent equivalent.

In Adventurers League, magic items are obtained during adventures (1-3 consummables plus 1 permanent per 4 hours session in average).

But I'd like to know if it's possible for an AL charcter to buy a magic item (possibly using downtime) instead of finding it as aventuring loot. Is it possible for...

1. Permanent ones? (Like boots of speed)
2. Consumable ones? (Like potion of growth)

From what I understand it's supposed to be difficult to find magic items available for buying, even consumable ones, but I'm asking if it still might be possible for when you want a very specific item, have more than enough money to buy it and are willing to travel far to go buy it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Generally, no...

The [Adventurers League Players Pack](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) contains the documents that detail your options in AL play. Purchases are restricted to items in the PHB. The only potion available for sale without special documentation is the basic Potion of Healing. There are no other magic items in the PHB - no potions, no scrolls - so they can't be purchased either.

### ...unless you're of sufficient rank in a faction...

Characters who reach rank 3 in their faction can use downtime and gold to acquire magic items from a very limited list: +1 weapons, shields, and armor are available to all faction members, and each faction allows access to a single uncommon item and a single rare item.

### ...attend an event featuring Fai Chen's Fantastic Faire...

Fai Chen's is available to public events of sufficient size that register with WoTC for it in advance. Fai Chen trades (but does not sell) permanent magic items, sells scrolls up to 5th level (one per transaction per event), strange trinkets, and occasionally special mounts and property deeds.

### ...or adventure in Chult.

There is a very small number of magical weapons and shields, plus scrolls and potions, available for purchase *only* to characters playing Season 7 content - DDAL modules and Tomb of Annihilation. These purchases are only available as a downtime activity.

Comment: This answer references an out of date version of the D&D Adventurers League Player's Guide. The most recent version says that "Spell scrolls and potions can be purchased for prices listed under Appendix A: Shared Campaigns in Xanathar’s Guide to Everything in addition to any component costs.". Reference Player's Guide on https://dnd.wizards.com/adventurers-league

Answer (score 12):

## Yes, in AL you can buy potions, scrolls and magical items but there are limitations...

Even though Xanathar’s Guide to Everything has an [entire section dedicated to buying magical items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#BuyingaMagicItem), there are additional clarifications on p. 174. (Note that though the rest of XGE Appendix A doesn't apply currently to Adventurers League, the statement below is accurate in referring to current practices in AL adventures.):

> Characters can use their monetary treasure to purchase anything from
> the equipment lists in chapter 5 of the Player’s Handbook. In
> addition. **the Adventurers League allows characters to purchase potions
> and spell scrolls**...A spell scroll can be purchased only by a
> character who is capable of casting the spell in question.

## Spending downtime is one limitation...

For the nuance in your question about “possibly using downtime” - there are in-adventure opportunities in Adventurer’s League to buy magical items but note that there are often limitations including spending downtime.

For example, in Tomb of Annihilation downtown costs and magical items sold are cited in the [TOA Primer](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/ToAPrimerv1.pdf):

> ...While the merchant princes are happy to sell the
>  items over which they hold monopoly, doing so can
>  be time consuming. Characters wishing to purchase
>  goods from the merchant princes must spend **10
>  downtime days** arranging a meeting, negotiating
>  prices, and coordinating for impartial intermediaries
>  to accept, transfer gold during the transaction. At the
>  end of the ten days, you may make one purchase—
>  either a single permanent magic item, or up to their
>  limit in other items (see, below).

## Potions and scrolls can be bought in this AL adventure:

> ...In Tomb of Annihilation, the merchant Wakanga in Port Nyanzaru sells potions (common & uncommon)
>  and scrolls (1st, 2nd and 3rd level)

## Magic items can be bought in this AL adventure:

> ...In Tomb of Annihilation: Ekene-Afa. This Merchant Prince has a small
>  selection of magic items (p.25) readily available for a
>  modest price. These items can’t be traded and the
>  permanent magic items increases the character’s
>  magic item count by one. The character may
>  purchase a single item or no more than 10 pieces of
>  +1 ammunition in a single transaction before she
>  refuses the character further service.

Outside of AL adventures, using downtime, you can only buy non-magical and magical items listed in the Player’s Handbook. Currently, the only potion in the PHB is a Potion of Healing and there are no scrolls.

## Magic items also cannot be sold by PCs.

What can be sold is also limited. According to the [AL documentation](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/magic-items-and-rewards-dd-adventurers-league):

> The first rule is relatively simple. There will be some rare
> opportunities to buy magic items with gold, but never to sell them.
> Adding more magic items into the world is okay; characters that get
> more items simply won't get items in contention after an adventure
> session. We just have to preserve a character's total permanent magic
> item count in order keep things balanced.

## Non-AL games do have guidelines for purchases.

This is in contrast to non-AL games which can allow downtime magical item purchases per Xanathar’s guide:

> **Buying a Magic Item**
>
> Purchasing a magic item requires time and money to
> seek out and contact people willing to sell items. Even then, there is
> no guarantee a seller will have the items a character desires.
>
> Resources. Finding magic items to purchase requires at least one
> work week of effort and 100 gp in expenses. Spending more time and
> money increases your chance of finding a high-quality item.

Additional details and tables are provided for rolling on the outcome of the search.

Comment: Unfortunately, @GaelL, the XGTE references are completely irrelevant to Adventurers League play. This answer is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Oh... i'll remove the checker for now then.

Comment: @GaelL I believe this edited answer is now foundationally correct

Comment: The passages from Appendix A from XGE have not been adopted by AL for the current season. They include some significant changes that AL will not adopt mid-season. This answer may become more accurate in the future, but for now it is using text not considered part of AL play - only the classes, spells, and magic items (when granted in modules) apply to AL play.

Comment: Of note, the section in XTGE that says "the Adventurers League allows characters to purchase potions and spell scrolls" is supported and part of AL play as the spoiler reveals.

Comment: @Praxiteles The ToA Primer modifies ToA for DDAL purposes. In DDAL play, you *must* spend downtime: "Characters wishing to purchase goods from the merchant princes must spend 10 downtime  days arranging a meeting, negotiating prices, [...]"

Comment: @Praxiteles The DDAL Reference for XGE says the entirety of Appendix A is "...not part of the D&D Adventurers League at this time".  Your first heading is therefore invalid. Your second heading is invalid due to the ToA Primer. Your third section does not link to current documentation. Your fourth and final is out-of-context for a question tagged DDAL. In effect, this entire answer is wrong.

Comment: @T.J.L. That is getting unnecessarily personal. Getting personal isn't inherently rude, but it's an excellent way to escalate an argument and/or derail constructive feedback.

Comment: @Praxiteles That was getting unnecessarily personal of T.J.L., but not a character attack. As our user behaviour guide says, we expect users who see a hostile interaction to disengage, not retaliate, and flag it for moderator attention. Please avoid escalating such things.

Comment: (I've removed the involved comments.)

Comment: @T.J.L. (1) Thanks. The downtime reference is fixed. We differ in opinion that the other headings are "wrong." (2) While true that XGE Appendix A rules are not used by AL. The quoted statement isn't a *rule*. It is a factual *observation* in the text that is supported by ToA itself.  (3) The link cited may be old but the guideline is up-to-date on being unable to sell magical items. If there's a change we are happy to update the link. (4) We left the fourth heading to give a baseline context for AL vs non-AL as this helps clarify how AL deviates.

Comment: This is the correct answer. See Players Guide in https://dnd.wizards.com/adventurers-league