# Is crafting scrolls allowed during downtime for Adventurers League characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

[Adventurers League guidelines](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/DDADVL_FAQv3.pdf) specify that characters can copy spells from each other using downtime.

Additionally, AL adventures like [Tomb of Annihilation](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/tomb-annihilation) offer opportunities to buy [common and uncommon scrolls from merchants](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/ToAPrimerv1.pdf).

Scrolls are consumables and do not count as permanent magic items - but yet still have varying rarity. (1st Level spells are Common. 2nd & 3rd: Uncommon. 4th and 5th: Rare. 6th & 7th: Very Rare. 8th & 9th: Legendary.)

The DMG p. 129 list costs for crafting magical items (like scrolls) using downtime with costs based on the item rarity. (Common: 100 gp. Uncommon 500 gp. Rare 5,000 gp. Very Rare 50,000 gp.  Legendary 500,000 gp.) The time to craft items is listed as 25 gp of progress per day.

XGTE pg. 133 modifies those costs with specific recommendations for scribing scrolls:

\begin{array}    
\text{Level} & Time &   Cost \\ \hline
\text{Cantrip} & \text{1 day}     & \text{15 gp} \\
    1^\text{st}   &  \text{1 day}     & \text{25 gp} \\
    2^\text{nd}   &  \text{3 days}     & \text{250 gp} \\
    3^\text{rd}   &  \text{1 workweek} & \text{500 gp} \\
    4^\text{th}   &  \text{2 workweeks} & \text{2,500 gp} \\
    5^\text{th}   &  \text{4 workweeks} & \text{5,000 gp} \\
    6^\text{th}   &  \text{8 workweeks} & \text{15,000 gp} \\
    7^\text{th}   &  \text{16 workweeks} & \text{25,000 gp} \\
    8^\text{th}   & \text{32 workweeks} & \text{50,000 gp} \\
    9^\text{th}   & \text{48 workweeks} & \text{250,000 gp} \\
\end{array}
AL seems to be specific about trying to limit permanent magic items and [limits what can be purchased](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112265/is-it-possible-for-an-adventurers-league-character-to-buy-a-magic-item-during-do).

But what about consumables? Can AL characters use downtime to craft scrolls from their own spells?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### As of Adventurers League Season 8, downtime may be used to scribe scrolls.

The "Downtime and Lifestyle" section of the [*Forgotten Realms Adventurers League Player's Guide* v8.2 (p. 4)](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/ALPGv82.pdf) states:

> ***Scribing Scrolls (XGE).*** You must know or be able to prepare a spell
>   before you can scribe it to a *spell scroll*. Its cost is in addition to
>   any component cost—regardless of whether it's consumed or not.